# Google analytics inconsistency in revenue stats

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics definitely has a problem in statistic display.

I do query with Date range 14-19 jul:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fim4avm75ohypqs/gatrust2.png

And have 12 transactions from iOS 5.1.1 and 0 from any others versions which is **very** strange.

Ok, who knows, maybe there is some abnormal users behavior.

But then i do same request, but for 1 day (18 Jul):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0q0lvuvzu4svy5/gatrust1.png

Now there is 6 transactions shown from others versions.

I have feeling that i may meet such inconsistencies in Google Analytics in other queries,
where i just do not see exact inconsistencies proof, but feel that provided information is not logical.

Does it mean, that i can’t trust to information provided by GA?
Just use it as some... sandbox tool?
Confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the inconsistencies are caused by [Google Analytics sampling](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en). When you have a lot of visits, Google Analytics (free plan) only takes only a part of them to show the corresponding stats.

If you look at the first of your captions, you can see in the upper right a box saying: "This report is based on 248.360 visits (8,36% of sessions)". So you are only seeing data from 8,36% of the real visits. You don't know what the other 91,64% did in that date range.

If you want reliable data with such high number of visits, Google Analytics (free) is probably not your best option. You could use [Google Analytics Premium](http://www.google.com/analytics/premium/) (quite expensive, but eliminates the sampling issue), other paid analytics software or some free alternative like [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) or [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/).